# How to get the timestamp from a Luxon DateTime object?

Tags: javascript, luxon

How can I get the Timestamp from a luxon dateTime object?

For example?

```js
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");

date = DateTime.now().setZone('utc');
date.endOf('day);

console.log(date.???) // should give something like 1629399474922
```

This should be the equivalent to javascript's `Date.getTime()` function.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Luxon docs are surprisingly silent on this, but after [some digging](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/moment?id=basics) I finally found it:

```js
date.toMillis(); 
// or 
date.valueOf();
```

Comment: You can also do `+date`